# How can I prevent automatic insertion of the year in a date input when min and max have the same year?

Tags: html, css

Apparently when you are setting the min and max attributes to the input type date within the same year, it is by default not letting you entering the year when you type. It looks like this:

[image]

```html
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">
```

so how do I disable this behavior and just have a regular input date
like this.
[image]

Comment: What would be the point of that if the user can't enter any other year value anyway?

Comment: I have other date fields, and I want to make the UI consistence.
and also I have some generic integration tests thats is entering the date in an automated way, and this will lead me to adjust alot of helper functions to be able to by pass the tests

Comment: #functionoverform #dontchangecodefortests

Comment: the tests is not the only reason, but ui consistance also

Comment: The `input type="date"` implementation is almost completely user-agent dependent. Blame [HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-\(type=date\)) and its lack of specificity. All it says is "If the element is mutable, the user agent should allow the user to change the date represented by its value, as obtained by parsing a date from it." That's pretty much it. There are no rules around how it should behave in regards to `min` or `max`, other than the validity of the control should be invalid if the value is below or above those values, respectively.